# Add IF statement to VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How would I add an IF statement to a VLOOKUP, so that the value returned is not found (i.e. 0, then instead of writing 0 it writes "John Owen"?

Code so far:

```
=VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9)
```

Comment: try `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9,0),"John Owen")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve Martin wrote, make sure to include `FALSE` in the 4th argument of the `VLOOKUP` function, but here is another version of that equation that returns the `VLOOKUP` value unless there is an error or zero:

`=if(not(iserror(vlookup(E:E,MASTER!A:I,9,False))),if(vlookup(E:E,MASTER!A:I,9,False)=0,"John Owen",vlookup(E:E,MASTER!A:I,9,False)),"John Owen")`

Comment: Will this insulate me against any N/A error messages

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier, yes, like Steve Martin's equation, this will convert all #N/A to "John Owen".  But this one will also convert 0 to "John Owen", which you may not want in the case of zero being a legitimate return value.

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP doesnt return 0 if a lookup is not found, it returns #N/A

If you are receiving a 0 , its because the lookup is found but the return column is blank

also make sure to include False in the VLOOKUP so that an exact match is needed.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9,False),"John Owen")
```

Comment: How do you get it to write something instead of 0 i.e. John Owen

Comment: =IF(VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9,False) = 0 , "John Owen",VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9,False))   using this.

Comment: How about #N/A - I'd like to replace that with "None"

Comment: =IF(VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9,False) = 0 , "John Owen",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9,False),"None"))     Using this

Comment: =IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9,False) = 0,"John Owen",VLOOKUP(E:E,Master!A:I,9,False)),"None")      try this